# Convert number in call log to Gmail Contact

Tags: contacts, call-history

When I get a call from some number I know I want to convert it into a contact. I expected to be able to do something like long press, then type the contact name, but when I long press and select add to contacts, it just kind of disappears into my contact list.
I'm sure everyone does this all the time, and so I am missing a really obvious way, but perhaps someone can enlighten me how to do this easily.

[edit]
Samsung Galaxy S, with Samsung overlay on Android 2.2, TMobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Dialer and Contacts apps can vary per phone model due to Android OS version, as well as manufacturer or carrier overlay.

Usually though, in the call log when you tap on the new number it gives you an "Add to contacts" option.  At that point it brings up a list of all contacts, so that you can add this number to an existing contact. However, there should also be a button to create a new contact, which is probably what you're overlooking.

Comment: Ah, so I click the add contacts button and it does carry the number through. That is indeed what I was missing. Thanks.